# How do you retrieve a list of the Local Machine Windows certificate store using Go?

Tags: go, certificate, certificate-store

Go allows you to pretty easily retrieve the Personal Windows cert store handle for the Current User using the following command:

```
store, err := syscall.CertOpenSystemStore(0, syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("MY")) // Personal Certificates
```

However, when I try to retrieve the Local Machine Personal cert store I always end up with either an empty store handle, and exception or error that the store was not found, CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND.

Alternatively, you can use this method:

```
    store, err := syscall.CertOpenStore(
       windows.CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 
       0,
       0,
       windows.CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
       uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("MY"))))
```

But when I swap out the values for the Local Machine store I start seeing the errors referenced above.

How do you successfully retrieve the Local Machine cert store in Windows using Go?

Comment: According to the docs for Windows API in C++ (which Go is based on) `CertOpenSystemsStoreW`: "Only current user certificates are accessible using this method, not the local machine store." So I believe you'll need to use `CertOpenStore`. Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopensystemstorew#remarks

Comment: Thanks, Devin. I have tried that and although it still works for Current User I am unable to convert it to work for Local Machine and that's what I'm looking for. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for adding `CertOpenStore` option as well. Have you tried replacing `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER` with `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE`?

Comment: That's what throws an exception because the store handle returned as zero: Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x70 0x7ffa61532cf0
PC=0x7ffa61532cf0
syscall.Syscall(0x7ffa61532c80, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
 C:/Go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:172 +0xc6
syscall.CertEnumCertificatesInStore(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
 C:/Go/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:1148 +0x9d
main.loadTheSystemCerts(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)

Answer (score 0):

You do use the following code snippet as mentioned in the comments above to retrieve the certs:

```
    store, err := syscall.CertOpenStore(
       windows.CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
       0,
       0,
       windows.CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
       uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("MY"))))
```

But there were a few things going on here as to why specifically it wasn't working initially:

1. You must run the program as Administrator otherwise the store will be returned as 0.
2. I was not running VS Code as Administrator: I thought I was, but you have to kill all instances in order to do so!
3. The code to retrieve the last error didn't seem to work in this situation in Go but when I switched over to working in C++ I did see the access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

Use CertOpenStore and along with CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, add CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG also. This should help get the list without running as Administrator.
Microsoft documentation for the flag is added below as reference:

> CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG - Open the store with the maximum set of
> allowed permissions. If this flag is specified, registry stores are
> first opened with write access and if that fails, they are reopened
> with read-only access.

I could see all the certificates in my local machine store listed that way.